# Set default chain in safe-wallet-web

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a safe instance for our chain at https://safe.shyft.network/

I am trying to figure out how to default the top-right pulldown to the first (and only)  item.

So far I have reviewed the code for NetworkSelector and CreateView->userInitialValues and it seems I'm close. I'm also debugging the deployed Safe instance which appears to default to Ethereum mainnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is through the query parameters (append `?chain=shyft` to the URL before redirecting to `https://safe.shyft.network/`) as it will keep the network in memory the second time it loads.

Comment: Hi Louis. I see that this works, and it led me down a track of investigating how it worked. The chain ID chosen is placed in session storage, a tuple with lastChainId in. it.  I found a statement to determine the chain ID and it says `return urlChainId || session.lastChainId || walletChainId || defaultChainId`

Then I found: `const defaultChainId = IS_PRODUCTION ? chains.eth : chains.sep`

Since I am working from a fork of the frontend (as seems to be requested/required, at least previously) I will override this.

Comment: Awesome! Happy that I could help. My way was a bit hacky, but yours seems much more suited. Cheers for letting us know!

Comment: I was going to put in a PR that checks the list of chains and chooses the numerically lowest if n<3 however the list of chains configured (returned by cgw) is not necessarily loaded at that point - or so it seems.  Beyond my reach in react, which I broadly find difficult to work with.   This could be improved, should I file an feature request?